# Responsive Design and onclick events

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries, inline-styles

I have a mobile menu button (only viewable with display:block by using media queries). When the button is clicked, my main "mobile" menu appears - I do this using simple javascript code (see below).

The problem ... if I click the button to expand the menu (changing the inline style from display:none to display:block), and then increase the browser size ... my menu doesn't disappear anymore. So, the inline style doesn't recognize the media query...

Below is the script that expands my menu...

```
<!-- Menu Expander / Toggle Visibility -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_menu(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Here are some of the styles.... you'll see the menu-mobile (which is the actual menu) and the mobile-menu-but (which is the button) is hidden (with display:none).  When the browser window is reduce, the button appears (with display:block in the media query), but the menu is still hidden. Then when you click the javascript button, the inline style display:block is added to set for the mobile-menu.

```
#mobile-menu-but, #menu-mobile { display:none; } 
#menu a, #menu a:link { padding: 15px 16px 12px 16px; }

@media (max-width: 790px) { 
  /* Switch to Mobile Menu when too long */
  #menu { display:none; } /* Hide Main Menu  */
  #mobile-menu-but { display:block; float:right; margin:0 20px 0 0; height:50px; padding:5px 0; } 
   #mobile-menu-but a { float:right; }
    .menu-txt { margin:10px 10px 0 0; float:right; }

    #menu-mobile { width:100%; background-color:#000; text-transform:uppercase; 
            font-size:16px; font-family:"AvantGarde", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } }
```

Comment: Inline styles really have nothing to do with media queries. Media queries say what part of a stylesheet applies based on the query criteria. Styles directly applied to elements always override what's in the stylesheet (well except for `!important`, which is usually a sign of doing something wrong).

Comment: me thinks you can just move `#menu { display:none; } ` out of the media query...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of directly manipulating element styles, you can add and remove class values in order to change element appearance. The rules for the class(es) can be affected by media queries because they'll go right into the stylesheet.

Modern browsers provide the `.classList` API:

```
function toggle_menu(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.classList.contains("showing"))
      e.classList.remove("showing");
    else
      e.classList.add("showing");
}
```

Now, in your CSS, you can have:

```
  #menu { display: none; }
  #menu.showing { display: block; }
```

If you only want to show the menu when the screen is big, add this *after* those lines above:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) { /* or whatever size you want */
    #menu.showing { display: none; }
  }
```

(There are other strategies for arranging rules in media queries, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting solution... I'll take a look at changing out the javascript for class substitution, instead of inline styles...

Comment: Thought about it ... but when I looked at it, there were some issues. If CLASS1 is set as display:block and CLASS2 is set as display:none, then the button will switch each class, causing the menu to appear and disappear (Great!). However, if the menu is visible with CLASS1, and then the page is reduced in size ... since CLASS1 is display:block, it will STAY VISIBLE. Which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Perfect. I was skeptical, but tried it. It worked. When you first mentioned it, I was thinking of simple class substitution, which I saw problems with. But, your way of adding/removing a single class worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy that I was able to help. There are all sorts of slight variations on this! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than add and remove the inline style with `e.style.display` , use

```
var e = document.getElementById("someID");
e.className = "someClass";
```

The problem you have is your inline style is overriding your CSS. Inline style will always have this priority (unless !important I guess - not sure about that).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick you can use to avoid JavaScript altogether:

```css
#menu {display:none}
#secret_checkbox {position: absolute; left:-9999px}
#secret_checkbox:checked + #menu {display: block}
```

```html
<label for="secret_checkbox">Click to open/close menu</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="secret_checkbox" />
<div id="menu">Hello!</div>
```

The label can be anywhere, the important thing is for the "hidden" checkbox to be immediately before the element it affects. This can make it a lot easier to change how things behave in CSS, plus it has the added benefit of working even if the user has JavaScript disabled ;)